# Xorg CPU at 100% and frozen when using HDMI cable

Tags: xorg, 16.10, hdmi

My Xorg has decided to stop working following updates and a reboot.

I have noticed that the Xorg process stays frozen at 100% CPU and the mouse/keyboard cannot be used if I boot the machine when connected by HDMI cable. If I connect the monitor in another way the problem does not occur.

How do I fix this issue so I can go back to using my HDMI cable?

I use intel motherboard and the iGPU

edit:

I was able to temporarily fix this issue by rolling the kernel back to version 4.8.0-41 from 4.8.0-42 (the latest availble for me)

How can I help get this bug diagnosed and fixed so it doesn't affect future versions?